# Passing URL information into a PHP page

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I am creating a website that will upload files per media device.  I want to create a URL so that the users pass in a deviceId, and a device signature, like:

```
http://somesite/device/deviceId?devicesig='ABC123'
```

and on the server, I pass this to my PHP page. ( I wrote a simple PHP page in the /device directory, so I know I'm serving content from that directory)

I'm using XAMPP on Windows, and I've configure my .htaccess:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ upload.php?q=$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

As well as set:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex upload.php
</IfModule>
```

I can access the URL as (missing the actual deviceId, of course)

```
http://localhost/device/upload.php?type=event&devicesig=e4876
```

But I want to access that URL as

```
http://localhost/device/A1234?type=event&devicesig=e4876
```

When I do so, I'm getting a "***The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.***" error.

How do I define/code such that the 'A1234' is considered as deviceId, not some part of the directory?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

As I read the comments below, it makes me wonder if my core assumption is incorrect.  First, I'm assuming that to get all files for a device, and to get a specific file, I would use the following GET statements:

```
GET /device/ABC123
GET /device/ABC123/file1.dat
```

Therefore, my POST statement would match that hierarchy:

```
POST /device/ABC123/file1.dat
```

To the comments below, does that mean that I have to take my entire URL, and parse it after the host and resource ('device'), in order to get the correct device ('ABC123')?

Comment: Your deviceId is variable, and devicesig is another variable? How is captured in PHP deviceId?

Comment: Both deviceId and devicesig are variables.  I'm trying to follow good RESTful practice by having ../device, and then managed devices underneath.  Once in PHP, I'll parse the URL, and using deviceId, I'll write the actual file being passed in to the correct directory:   /some/dir/deviceid/

Comment: So the final URL must be like this: http: //localhost/device/upload.php?deviceId=A1234&type=event&devicesig=e4876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ upload.php?q=$1 [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^device/(.*)$ /device/upload.php?deviceId=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Perfect - I'm now redirecting all traffic into my upload PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Why you just don't have an url like:
localhost/device?deviceId=A1234&type=event&devicesig=e4876

Comment: my client specified in his documented request that the resource part be /device/deviceId?type=event@devicesig=e4876.  My initial thought was more to your suggestion, but I was trying to figure out if his request is correct / my assumed solution is wrong.